# how can I detect the mouse cursor leaves the viewport when using QTableView class?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

I found the 'viewportEntered' signal of [QAbstractItemView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#viewportEntered) class which was the super class of the QTableView class. If I use this signal to do an action, I also need a way to undo this action when the mouse cursor leaves the viewport.

Comment: I found the leaveEvent of [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#leaveEvent) class. By reimplementing leaveEvent function, I can emit my self-defined siganl here.

Comment: Thanks to @eyllanesc. I did not notice the difference between the viewport of QTableView and the 'QTableView' widget itself when asking the quesion. Basically, I want to do an action when cursor enters the 'QTableView' widget and undo the action when cursor leaves the 'QTableView' widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to tracking in what moment the requirement that is indicated is fulfilled and then to emit the new signal:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    viewportLeaved = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.is_entered = False
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.viewportEntered.connect(self.on_viewportEntered)

    def on_viewportEntered(self):
        self.is_entered = True

    def viewportEvent(self, event):
        res = super(TableView, self).viewportEvent(event)
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
            if self.is_entered:
                self.viewportLeaved.emit()
                self.is_entered = False
        return res

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(TableView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if self.indexAt(event.pos()).isValid() and self.is_entered:
            self.viewportLeaved.emit()
            self.is_entered = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TableView()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(4, 5)
    w.setModel(model)
    w.viewportEntered.connect(lambda: print("viewportEntered", QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString()))
    w.viewportLeaved.connect(lambda: print("viewportLeaved", QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString()))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks again. After testing, your code works. Also, I find a way to do so by the leaveEvent of QWidget.

Comment: @C.Hobin The leaveEvent of the QtableView is not the leaveEvent of the viewport, the qtableview is viewport + headers.